# Android Studio Recycler View Remove Item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am trying to remove Items from my recycler view. Every time I click on an item in my recycler view it provides me with this error.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void uk.edu.le.co2103.myrecipebook.RecipeListAdapter.removeItem(int, java.util.List)' on a null object reference

I have made sure that my list has been initalized and used a log to ensure that both position and the list have values in them.

> List: [uk.edu.le.co2103.myrecipebook.Recipe@f4d5298, uk.edu.le.co2103.myrecipebook.Recipe@ca6aaf1]
>    D/MAIN ACTIVITY: Index: 0

Here is my Main Activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
RecipeListAdapter.OnItemClickListener  {
private static final String TAG = "MAIN ACTIVITY";
private static final int RESULT_UPDATED = 300;
private RecipeViewModel mRecipeViewModel;
    public static final int NEW_WORD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public String Name;
    public String Ingredients;
    public String Method;
    private RecipeListAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecipeDao recDao;
    Menu menu;
List<Recipe> recipesList = new ArrayList<>();

ListView search_items;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        RecipeListAdapter mAdapter = new RecipeListAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecipeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(RecipeViewModel.class);

        Log.d(TAG, "SIZE OF LIST: "+ recipesList);
        mRecipeViewModel.getAllRecipes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Recipe>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Recipe> recipes) {
                // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
                int size = mAdapter.getItemCount();
                Log.d(TAG, "List of List : " + recipes);
                recipesList= recipes;
                mAdapter.setWords(recipes);
            }
        });

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddRecipeActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_WORD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });



}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == NEW_WORD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> rData = data.getStringArrayListExtra(AddRecipeActivity.EXTRA_REPLY);
        String name = rData.get(0);
        String ingredients = rData.get(1);
        String method = rData.get(2);
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe(name, ingredients, method);
        RecipeViewModel.insert(recipe);
    }
   else {
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.empty_not_saved,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position, View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick Position: " + position);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Edit or Delete...");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            recipesList.get(position); //clicked item
            Intent update = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UpdateRecipeActivity.class);
            update.putExtra("Name", recipesList.get(position).getName()); //
            update.putExtra("Ingredients", recipesList.get(position).getIngredients());
            update.putExtra("Method", recipesList.get(position).getMethod());
            startActivity(update);

        }

    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            //Delete

            Log.d(TAG, "List: " + recipesList);
            Log.d(TAG, "Index: " + position);
            int removeIndex = position;
            recipesList.remove(removeIndex);


        }
    });
    alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Here is my adapter code

```
 public class RecipeListAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeListAdapter.RecipeViewHolder> {
private static final String TAG = "ADAPTER";
private OnItemClickListener mListener;


public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(int position, View view);
}
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}

class RecipeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final TextView recipeItemView;

    private RecipeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        recipeItemView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                if (mListener != null){
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        mListener.onItemClick(position, v);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);
    }
}

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<Recipe> mRecipes; // Cached copy of words

RecipeListAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public RecipeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
    return new RecipeViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecipeViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (mRecipes != null) {
        Recipe current = mRecipes.get(position);
        holder.recipeItemView.setText(current.getName());
    } else {
        // Covers the case of data not being ready yet.
        holder.recipeItemView.setText("No Recipes");
    }
}

void setWords(List<Recipe> recipes){
    mRecipes = recipes;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void deleteItem(final int position) {
    mRecipes.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mRecipes != null)
        return mRecipes.size();
    else return 0;
}
public interface OnNoteListener{}
```

}

Here is the full error output

```
2020-04-02 15:27:30.553 5522-5522/uk.edu.le.co2103.myrecipebook E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: uk.edu.le.co2103.myrecipebook, PID: 5522
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void uk.edu.le.co2103.myrecipebook.RecipeListAdapter.deleteItem(int)' on a null object reference
    at uk.edu.le.co2103.myrecipebook.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:133)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7464)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:955)
```

Comment: Hi Ethan, where is your removeItem func. I cannot see.

Comment: I was told in my assignment brief that I didn't need to do that, it said just keep the delete code in the main activity?

Comment: Okey, what is the problem now. Can you tell me.

Comment: Basically when I press delete on item it provides the error detailed above in the main thread. The item is removed but when I call NotifyDataSetChanged() or anything to do with that, the error pops up

Comment: Did you try  to add  noureldien mohamed code to your adapter and call func when  setNegativeButton click

Comment: I have implemented this but I still get the same error

Comment: You are using LiveData<List<Recipe>> recipeList. Change List<Recipe> recipeList.

Comment: I have changed all references of LiveData<List> to just list but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your adapter. I found some problems :

```
public class RecipeListAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeListAdapter.RecipeViewHolder> {
private static final String TAG = "ADAPTER";
private OnItemClickListener mListener;


public interface OnItemClickListener{
  void onItemClick(int position, View view);
}
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
  mListener = listener;
}

class RecipeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
private final TextView recipeItemView;

private RecipeViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    recipeItemView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if (mListener != null){
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                    mListener.onItemClick(position, v);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    mListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);
}
}

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<Recipe> mRecipes; // Cached copy of words

RecipeListAdapter(Context context) {
  mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public RecipeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
  View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
  return new RecipeViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecipeViewHolder holder, int position) {
  if (mRecipes != null) {
     Recipe current = mRecipes.get(position);
     holder.recipeItemView.setText(current.getName());
} else {
    // Covers the case of data not being ready yet.
     holder.recipeItemView.setText("No Recipes");
  }
}

void setWords(List<Recipe> recipes){
  mRecipes = recipes;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void deleteItem(final int position) {
  mRecipes.remove(position);
  notifyItemRemoved(position);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
  if (mRecipes != null)
    return mRecipes.size();
  else return 0;
}
public interface OnNoteListener{}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How should I implement this in my main activity as unfortunately I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you edit your question  last version of your codes.

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: You should remove recipesList.remove(removeIndex). and add mAdapter.deleteItem(removeIndex)

Comment: Sorry for this, but even still having the mAdapter remove it in the main activity it still outputs the error

Comment: Can you share error log

Comment: I have updated the main thread with the full error ouput

Comment: I have updated the main thread with the full error ouput

Comment: Yesss, I found, RecipeListAdapter mAdapter = new RecipeListAdapter(this); problem is this line. change like this : mAdapter = new RecipeListAdapter(this);

Comment: Because we called mAdapter in onItemClick,  but mAdapter is always null this way. 
We missed here .

Answer (score 0):

you can use it

```
public void deleteItem(final int position) {

 recipeList.remove(position);
 notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: I still get the same error